# How to get Pop up window control item from c# page

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-scraping, screen-scraping, web-controls

I am working for a screen scrapping application from windows application

I can automatically navigate through login page and all the pages using the we browser methods and sometimes having to use the '.Click' to trigger buttons on some of the pages.

Here's the problem. When I do the final 'click' to get my data, web browser opens up a new explorer window(pop up windows) that contains the another link button and I have to do click on this link button using c# to get my final data.

How can I access the new window(pop up window) to scrape it?

I am using below code and this code open the URL in new pop up window.

```
 HtmlElement toollinkbutton = WebBrowser1.Document.Window.Document.Body.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")[48];
toollinkbutton .InvokeMember("click");
```

Answer (score 1):

The new window may be due to target="_blank" or javascript and using InvokeMember will result in the new window opening. Add a handler to the WebBrowser control NewWindow event and handle the click by calling Navigate() instead.

```
private string url = "";

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
    WebBrowser1.NewWindow += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(webBrowser1_NewWindow);
}

void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    HtmlElementCollection links = WebBrowser1.Document.Links;
    foreach (HtmlElement var in links)
    {
        var.AttachEventHandler("onclick", LinkClicked);
    }
}

private void LinkClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    HtmlElement link = WebBrowser1.Document.ActiveElement;
    url = link.GetAttribute("href");
}

void webBrowser1_NewWindow(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowser webBrowser = (WebBrowser)sender;
    HtmlElement link = webBrowser.Document.ActiveElement;
    Uri urlNavigated = new Uri(link.GetAttribute("href"));
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(url);
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.but the solution is not worked as I expect. I am scrapping a HTTPS website.
I am using WebBrowser control from the windows application and loading the page in to these browser and parsing the data.When the login page completes  and click on the link, then it now open a new internet explorer window as pop up window.But right now I cant able to get these pop up data beacuse it runs as in separate internet window.How can I get these data in these pop up window.

Comment: I am getting pop up blocked message , even I allow pop up from the browser when navigate using your above code